# Connect to Acrobat's IAC (interapplication communication)

Tags: activex, ole, hta, acrobat-sdk

I am trying to automate some non-trivial task* with Adobe's Acrobat XI.

I think the way to go is using Acrobat's IAC, which seems to be well-documented, eg. [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/interapplication_communication.html).
However, I could not figure out how to *access* the application object, eg. from within an HTA. I mean: **How do I get the `app` object mentioned in the API documentation?**

It feels like I am missing something very obvious. However, I have been searching and trying unsuccessfully for quite a while now.

Alternatively, any other suggestion how to perform complicated stuff (see footnote) in Acrobat is appreciated.

---

*The task is concatenating 1 to n JPG files into a PDF/A document (like, tens of thousands of times). The mapping is given through a TSV file or something alike. The requirement of generating PDF/A *which pass Adobe's validation* forces me to use Acrobat, at least for this last step.

Comment: Are you using .net? Are you missing a reference to IAC? try: SET gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

Comment: I'll use whatever works. And the reference name "AcroExch.App" works! I couldn't find this identifier in the API reference; but now that you pointed it out to me, I see it in a paragraph ''title''... Well, now this whole question seems quite useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using .net? Are you missing a reference to IAC?

try: SET gApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")